# JavaScript Write to Other Website

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web

I am writing a code on one website that has data and need help to send that data to another website.  Any suggestions using javascript or anything else.

Comment: Please "do you homework" - provide some code you're trying to use - then someone can explain you how to fix errors. Now there not enough information to help you

Comment: Please could you provide some more information. What type of data needs to be sent, for example? And do you have to ability to edit the website that it is being sent to, or is it an external site?

Comment: I hope you didn't trying to violate [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You can "talk" to other websites only if those sites allow it, using [CORS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), html5 postMessage etc etc.

Comment: it is an array of doubles

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is to use a form or AJAX request to send the data to a Web server, which then writes the data to a database. The database can be shared with the other website, or the server can expose the data through an API.

If you only want to write client-side code, then you may be able to use a backend-as-a-service like parse.com, Firebase, or mongoHQ. You can also use the Dropbox Datastore API if you want to store information only at the level of individual users: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore.